# Changing personalized user settings PHP

Tags: php, forms

I'm working on a PHP login page. The first page shows two forms, a login and register form and does some form verification. When a user logs in it reads their information out of a text file. The information is listed as

```
username;password;fname;lname;pagetitle;bgcolor;imgURL
```

with the end of line occurring after the image. This info then populates a form on the next page so that the user can edit it if they so choose. I have no idea though how to read the line from the file when the user submits the changes and then write it back to the file. I also need to know how I can change the bgcolor and imgURL when these changes are submitted.

My current code is listed below.

```
<?php
session_start();
$bkcolor = "red";
   if(isset($_GET['exit'])){
      session_unset();
      session_destroy();
   }
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
?>
<h1>Welcome to First Last's Assignment 11 PHP page!</h1>
<?php
echo"Hello, ".$_SESSION['fname']. " " .$_SESSION['lname']."!";
//echo $_SESSION['image'];
?>

<form name  = "logoutForm" action = "assignment11.php" method = "get">
   <input type = "hidden" name = "logout" value = "doLogout"><br>
   <input type = "submit" name = "exit" value = "Logout" />
</form></div>
<br><hr><br>

<form name = "editAccountForm" action = "assignment11.php" method = "get">
   First name:<input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "<?php echo"      $_SESSION['fname']; ?>" /><br>
   Last name:<input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php echo     $_SESSION['lname']; ?>" /><br>
   Title:<input type = "text" name = "title" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['title'];     ?>" /><br>
   <input type = "hidden" name = "edit" value = "true">
   <input type = "submit" name = "edit1" value = "Edit Account Info" />
</form>
<?php
}else{
?>

<head><title>Welcome to First Last's Assignment 11 PHP page!</title></head>
<body bgcolor = "<?php echo $bkcolor; ?>" > 
<h1>Welcome to First Last's Assignment 11 PHP page!</h1>
<br>
<div id = "login">
If you have an existing account login here:<br>
<form method = "get" action = "assignment11.php" name = "loginForm">
   Username: <input type = "text" name = "user1" /><br>
   Password: <input type = "password" name = "pass1" /><br>
<input type = "submit" name = "login" value = "Login!" />
</form></div>
<br><hr><br>

<div id = "create">
If you'd like to create an account login here:<br>
<form method = "get" action = "assignment11.php" name = "createForm">
   Username: <input type = "text" name = "user" /><br>
   Password: <input type = "password" name = "pass" /><br>
   First Name: <input type = "text" name = "first" /><br>
   Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "last" /><br>
   <input type = "hidden" name = "create" value = "true" />
   <input type = "submit" name = "register" value = "Create Account!" />
   <p id = "incorrect"></p>
</form></div>

<?php
}
   $image = '<img src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb    /9/94/Stick_Figure.svg/170px-Stick_Figure.svg.png />';
   //$bkcolor = "yellow";
   $myfile = fopen("assignment11-account-info.txt", "a+");
   $file = fread($myfile,filesize("assignment11-account-info.txt"));
   $title = "Welcome to First Last's Assignment 11 PHP page!";
   $result = file_get_contents("assignment11-account-info.txt");

   $result = str_replace(PHP_EOL,";",$result);
   $result = explode(";",$result);

   if(isset($_GET['register'])){
   $user = $_GET['user'];
   $password = $_GET['pass'];
   $first = $_GET['first'];
   $last = $_GET['last'];
   $found = false;

   if(empty($user)){
      echo"Enter a username.";
   }else{
      $user = $user;
   }
   if(empty($password)){
      echo"Enter a password.";
   }
   else{
      $password = $password;
   }
   if(empty($first)){
      echo"Enter first name.";
   }
   else{
      $first = $first;
   }
   if(empty($last)){
      echo"Enter last name.";
   }
   else{
      $last = $last;
   }
//   $found = true;
   for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++){
      if($result[$i] === $user){
         $found = true;
         echo"Username unavailable";
         break;
      }
   }
      if($found == false){
         $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
         $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
         $_SESSION['fname'] = $_GET['first'];
         $_SESSION['lname'] = $_GET['last'];
         $_SESSION['title'] = $title;
         echo "HERE!";
         fwrite($myfile,$user.";".$password.";".$first.";".$last.";".$bkcolor.";".$title.";".$image.PHP_EOL);
        echo"<script>document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'none'</script>";
        echo"<script>document.getElementById('create').style.display = 'none'</script>";
?>

<form name  = "logoutForm" action = "assignment11.php" method = "get">
   <input type = "hidden" name = "logout" value = "doLogout"><br>
   <input type = "submit" name = "exit" value = "Logout" />
```

---

```
 <form name = "editAccountForm" action = "assignment11.php" method = "get">
   First name:<input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "<?php echo     $_SESSION['fname']; ?>" /><br>
   Last name:<input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php echo     $_SESSION['lname']; ?>" /><br>
   Title:<input type = "text" name = "title" value = "<?php echo $title; ?>" /><br>
   Background color:<input type = "text" name = "bkcolor" value = "<?php echo     $bkcolor;     ?>" /><br>
   Image:<input type = "text" name = "image" size = "100" value = "testing" /><br>
   <input type = "hidden" name = "edit" value = "true">
   <input type = "submit" name = "edit1" value = "Edit Account Info" />
</form>
<?php
      }
   }

   if(isset($_GET['login'])){
      $user = $_GET['user1'];
      $password = $_GET['pass1'];
//      $image = '<img src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Stick_Figure.svg/170px-Stick_Figure.svg.png />';
//      echo $image;
      for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++){
         if($result[$i] === $user && $result[$i+1] === $password){
            echo"<script>document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'none'</script>";
            echo"<script>document.getElementById('create').style.display = 'none'</script>";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            $_SESSION['fname'] = $result[$i+2];
            $_SESSION['lname'] = $result[$i+3];
            $_SESSION['title'] = $title;
//            $_SESSION['image'] = $image;
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            echo"Hello, ".$_SESSION['fname']." ".$_SESSION['lname']."!";
//            echo $_SESSION['image'];            
?>

<form name  = "logoutForm" action = "assignment11.php" method = "get">
   <input type = "hidden" name = "logout" value = "doLogout"><br>
   <input type = "submit" name = "exit" value = "Logout" />
</form></div>
<br><hr><br>

<form name = "editAccountForm" action = "assignment11.php" method = "get">
   First name:<input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['fname']; ?>" /><br>
   Last name:<input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['lname']; ?>" /><br>
   Title:<input type = "text" name = "title" value = "<?php echo $title; ?>" /><br>
   Background color:<input type = "text" name = "bkcolor" value = "<?php echo $bkcolor; ?>" /><br>
   Image:<input type = "text" name = "image" size = "100" value = "testing" /><br>
   <input type = "hidden" name = "edit" value = "true">
   <input type = "submit" name = "edit1" value = "Edit Account Info" />
</form>
<?php
         }
         else if($result[$i] === $user && $result[$i+1] !== $password){
            echo"Incorrect password!";
         }
/*         else if($result[$i] !== $user){
            echo"Invalid username. Have you registered?";
            break;
         }*/
      }
   }
   if(isset($_GET['exit'])){
      session_unset();
      session_destroy();
   }

   if(isset($_GET['edit1'])){
      for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++){
         if($result[$i] == $_SESSION['username']){

$_SESSION['username'].";".$_SESSION['password'].";".$_GET['fname'].";".$_GET['lname'].";".$_GET['title'].";".$_GET['bkcolor'].";".$_GET['image'].PHP_EOL);
         }
      }

   }

//   print_r($_SESSION);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: forget the txt file, it's impossible to maintain, use mysql

Comment: I can't use mysql. It's for educational purposes so it has to be a .txt file.

Comment: The you're going to need [`lock`](http://php.net/lock) for writing to that file, and [`fgetscv`](http://php.net/fgetscv) or [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) for reading. (Or [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) if you want to be resourceful). What you have there is a "CSV" file.

Comment: Sorry, there is no simple and easy solution. You have to parse the whole file each time, either line by line until you find the username using `fopen` and `fgets` or using `file` to get the whole file in an array, loop through the array and remember the index at which the user is. Then you can recompose the line and the whole file and save it

Comment: I'll try to read up on those Mario. None of them were ever discussed in class so I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Another thought I had was can something like this be done with cookies?